# How to catch require_once/include_once exception?

Tags: php, exception, include, try-catch, require

I'm trying to write code similar this:

```
<?php
$includes = array(
    'non_existing_file.php', //This file doesn't exist.
);

foreach ($includes as $include) {
    try {
        require_once "$include";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $message = $e->getMessage();
        echo "
            <strong>
              <font color=\"red\">
                A error ocurred when trying to include '$include'.
                Error message: $message
              </font>
            </strong>
        ";
    }
}
```

I'd tried `require_once` and `include_once`, but `try catch` doesn't catch the exception.

How could I catch this **fatal errors/warning** exceptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error)) worked fine to me:

```
register_shutdown_function('errorHandler');

function errorHandler() { 
    $error = error_get_last();
    $type = $error['type'];
    $message = $error['message'];
    if ($type == 64 && !empty($message)) {
        echo "
            <strong>
              <font color=\"red\">
              Fatal error captured:
              </font>
            </strong>
        ";
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($error);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

Comment: @LSerni Edited =)

Answer (score 17):

Since include/require does not throw an exception, check before if the file your want to include exists and is readable. eg:

```
$inc = 'path/to/my/include/file.php';

if (file_exists($inc) && is_readable($inc)) {

    include $inc;

} else {

    throw new Exception('Include file does not exists or is not readable.');
}
```

Comment: I wouldnt like this because the problem could not exist just as the file exists, but when requiring it.

Comment: good point. an additional `is_readable` would be much more better.

Comment: `include file.php;` could include this file from everywhere in the PHP include path. So `file_exists()` does not make sense here... Espacially if the programmer does not know how the include path will look like on the users server...

Comment: missing semicolon after `$inc = 'path/to/my/include/file.php'`

Answer (score 6):

These functions are throwing [E_COMPILE_ERROR](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php), and are not catchable like this.

To handle these errors see [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

Comment: Thanks, this is IMO the best solution to the problem.